# linear model: long or wide data frame?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to make sense of multiple linear regression in R.

I have a data frame that looks like this. You can see that there's a `Source_Group` category with different channel information and there's also a `Spend` column that shows money spent.

```
       Date Source_Group    Spend Total_Orders year month
1 2021-01-01          OTT 12359.16           28 2021     1
2 2021-01-01  Paid Search 17266.55          190 2021     1
3 2021-01-01  Paid Social  6799.28           40 2021     1
4 2021-01-01      YouTube     0.00            7 2021     1
5 2021-01-02          OTT  9104.31           42 2021     1
```

And here is `dput` code to recreate some of this first data frame:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
18629), class = "Date"), Source_Group = structure(c(11L, 12L, 
13L, 17L, 11L), .Label = c("Article Or Blog", "Audio", "Direct", 
"Email", "From A Friend", "From Contacts", "Influencer", "Organic Search", 
"Organic Social", "Other", "OTT", "Paid Search", "Paid Social", 
"Pepperjam", "Podcast", "Reddit", "YouTube", "Organic", "Peoplehype"
), class = "factor"), Spend = c(12359.16, 17266.55, 6799.28, 
0, 9104.31), Total_Orders = c(28, 190, 40, 7, 42), year = c(2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18629
), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to take a look at the number of orders that come from different the money spent in different marketing channels and make some decisions about how to allocate resources.

Using that dataframe, do I create a linear model like this:

```
linear_model_long_format <- lm(Total_Orders ~ Spend + Source_Group, df)
```

Or should I restructure the data frame into a wide format using this code:

[image]:

```
df_wide <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = Source_Group, values_from = Spend)
```

As a result my data frame would look like this:

And here is dput code to recreate some of this second data frame:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
18629), class = "Date"), Total_Orders = c(28, 190, 40, 7, 42), 
    year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), month = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    OTT = c(12359.16, 0, 0, 0, 9104.31), `Paid Search` = c(0, 
    17266.55, 0, 0, 0), `Paid Social` = c(0, 0, 6799.28, 0, 0
    ), YouTube = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), groups = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(18628, 18629), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:4, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df_wide $OTT[is.na(df_wide $OTT)] <- 0
df_wide $`Paid Search`[is.na(df_wide $`Paid Search`)] <- 0
df_wide $`Paid Social`[is.na(df_wide $`Paid Social`)] <- 0
df_wide $YouTube[is.na(df_wide $YouTube)] <- 0
```

I notice I would have to turn the NA values to 0 in order to not get an error.

My linear model this way I think would look like this:

```
linear_model_wide_format <- lm(Total_Orders ~ OTT + `Paid Search` + `Paid Social` + YouTube, df_wide)
```

Online posts I see seem to use this wider format for linear models where each column is a variable, but at the same time I know long format is generally preferred in R and also those 0s make me really doubt that the wide format is the way to go. I'm really not sure.

Comment: It would be best if you can edit your question to include the data shown as *text* (i.e. cut-and-paste into a code block) rather than screenshots; it's more accessible in many ways

Comment: Hey I just did a dput for the head of each data frame if that helps good suggestion

Comment: See my edit.  The `dput()` format is most computer-friendly, but a text tabular format is best for humans (including visually impaired humans with screen readers ...)

Comment: that's a good edit. thank you for the info. How did you get text tabular format for table so fast?

Comment: I pasted your `dput()` code into an R session, printed the object, then cut-and-pasted the resulting output into a code block in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long format is almost definitely better. If you fit the model in long format R will convert the factor variable into a set of binary (dummy) variables using a *contrast matrix*; this is a little bit confusing but will allow you to make various comparisons among groups.

Using `equatiomatic::extract_eq()`, we get

[image: latex equation]

You may also want to try the interaction model `Total_Orders ~ Spend*Source_Group`, which will allow you to compare the differences in the effect of spending on total orders *across* source groups, i.e. how does the expected change in total orders per unit of increase in spending (the beta_1 parameter above) differ between source groups?

[image: more complex latex equation]

I pasted the `extract_eq()` results into https://quicklatex.com/ to get the LaTeX renderings

Comment: I thought that you only use the asterisk for the interaction in a linear model if the variable are collinear? Am I wrong on this? What do you mean by "across" source groups?

Comment: I think you might be wrong ... will edit my question to try to clarify a bit.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. This data frame, for context, is kind of like four data frames put together. the information for YouTube comes from a different place than OTT and you spend money on one or the other. So the idea of putting an asterisk for an interaction model never occurred to me but maybe I'm not understanding